# Android tabs implemented with Fragments and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

My application has 3 tabs, each represented by `Fragments`. There is a custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` which also implements `ActionBar.TabListener`. Initially my FragmentPagerAdapter was returning new instances of fragments in  `public Fragment getItem(int index)` method. Also, my TabListener implementation was instantiating Fragments and showing/hiding them in the `onTabSelected/onTabUnselected`. Unfortunately this approach doesn't fit me well, because in this case each Fragment is actually created twice. What I want is to create it once and then just hide/show, when necessary.

For that I have instantiated my fragment earlier in the activity and passed them to the PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tabs_layout);

        List<Fragment> fragments = initTabFragments();

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        TabsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, viewPager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        for (int tab_name : tabs) {
            Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        actionBar.addTab(tab.setText(tab_name).setTabListener(pagerAdapter));
        }
...
    }

    private List<Fragment> initTabFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(3);
    fragments.add(SherlockFragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(SherlockFragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(SherlockFragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment3.class.getName()));
    return fragments;
    }
```

Then in the PagerAdapter I just return fragment:

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    return fragments.get(index);
}
```

To handle Tab selection there is the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
int position = tab.getPosition();
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + position;
    Fragment fragment = context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
        if (fragment == null) {
            ft.add(viewPagerId, fragments.get(0), tag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.show(fragments.get(0));
        }
        break;
        }
        case 1:
            if (fragment == null) {
                ft.add(viewPagerId, fragments.get(1), tag);
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(fragments.get(1));
            }
            break;
            }

    }

 @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
        ft.hide(fragments.get(0));
        break;
        case 1:
        ft.hide(fragments.get(1));
        break;
        }
}
```

In this case each fragment is instantiated once. And the first tab is shown correctly, but when I switch between tabs second and third tabs are empty (just white background). Why?

I was trying to add fragment to a container `android.R.id.content`, but exception was thrown: `Can't change container ID of fragment...`. I found out that it is because when Fragment is returned in `getItem` method it is added to a `viewPager` container. That why I use viewPagerId when add fragment to a transaction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a ExampleFragment class defined that extends Fragment. Something like shown below

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private View categoryView;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        categoryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) categoryView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        return categoryView;
    }

    public ViewPager returnViewPager() {
        return mViewPager;
    }
}
```

main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ExampleFragmentActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="somepackage.ExampleFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then add this in the `onCreate()` of ExampleFragmentActivity

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
mViewPager = fragment.returnViewPager();

fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why should I inflate viepager layout in the Fragment, which should actually contain the list view?